# Spry menu doesnt work on another server

Tags: dreamweaver, flash-cs5, spry

I created a few linked pages on dreamweaver. When I send them all through a zipped file to another computer to test it, the image on all pages works fine. However the spry menu does not appear. Instead, all the text from the menu appears vertically down the page, despite including all of the spry assets in the zip file.

Anybody know how I can fix this or have an idea of where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If all of the menu code is appearing as a list, it means that the page is not finding the Spry CSS and/or JS files.  Check the calls to those files in the HTML again.